# How to create a shared library (.so) having two functions with the same name

Tags: shared-libraries, libc, newlib

I first compiled two object files  (.o) :

- string-memcpy.o
- machine-memcpy.o

They both define a function `memcpy()`. Now, I want to create a shared library (.so) with :

```
gcc -shared -o test.so string-memcpy.o machine-memcpy.o
```

This fails due to *"multiple definition of `memcpy`"*. Is there a way to do this ? Thank you!

In fact I encounter this problem when I am trying to compile a shared library for libc (newlib-1.16). I can only find on Internet how to build a static library from it. So any hint on how to achieve this is appreciated.

Comment: I noticed I can create static library using "ar rc ../libc.a *.o" with no problem. so what is the difference?

And is there similar problem in building glibc shared library? (I am not familar with glibc). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A static library is just a '.ar' file (a primitive predecessor to tar) containing the .o files . Nothing involved in the process knows or cares whether there are symbol conflicts. If multiple .o files in a .ar file contain the same symbol, the linker will pick the first one it sees. If it then later tries to use the other .o file to satisfy another symbol, you'll get an error.

A shared lib, on the other hand, is linker output, and the linker is not willing to create files with duplicate symbol names.

There are some complex options to `ld` that might allow you to work around this, but they also might just make your problems worse.